# Tensorflow on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried to run keras in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
```

Installed:

```
tensorflow   - 1.12.0
Keras        - 2.2.4
```

I get the following error:

```
F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow
library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't
available on your machine. Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I resolve the above issue?

Comment: Remove tensorflow and reinstall. I would recommend using anaconda, with a fresh clean environment.

Comment: Thanks @Dinari i ll check and get back to you.